# jQuery repeat script

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem with images fadeIn, fadeOut. Images are loading without proper delay. Here is the code:

```
    $(function goback(){


    $("#img1").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#img2").delay(5000).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#img3").delay(5000).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
    (function(){

    setTimeout(goback(), 5000);
})();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of JQuery you are using. It might be old.

This code works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/b85hx/15/

Using your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/b85hx/16/